Media player notification created with foreground service not showing on lock screen (Android 13, SDK 34)

Called from HomeActivity
This is the part where the service function is called from the main activity. It is called differently depending on the version.
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MyService.class);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
} else {
    startService(serviceIntent);
}


MyService Class
The NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH is specified. The setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) is set.
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "TTS_NOTI";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 999;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        createNotificationChannel();
        showTTSNotification();  // Create notification
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "TTS Notifications",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            channel.setDescription("Notifications for TTS control");
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    private void showTTSNotification() {
        // MediaSession setup
        MediaSessionCompat mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "TTS_MediaSession");
        mediaSession.setActive(true);

        // Set large icon
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

        // Create intent to bring the app to the foreground
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        // Create NotificationCompat.Builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentTitle("Song Title")
                .setContentText("Artist Name")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setStyle(new MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.play_prev, "Previous", getPendingIntent("PREVIOUS")))
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.play, "Play", getPendingIntent("PLAY_PAUSE")))
                .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.play_next, "Next", getPendingIntent("NEXT")));

        // Run the service in the foreground
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("MyService", "Service destroyed");
    }
}


Parts written in AndroiManifest.xml
And I have added the necessary permissions in the AndroidManifest.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />


<serviceandroid:name=".etc.MyService"
android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
android:permission="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<receiver android:name=".etc.NotificationReceiver"/>



I have searched extensively on Google but have not found a solution. I would greatly appreciate any links or information that you could provide.

What is your target sdk?  By (Android 13, SDK 34) do you mean the problem is on device with android 13? SDK 34 is android 14.

Hello, the target SDK is 34.
I am testing on devices with Android versions 13 and 14.
The issue occurs identically on both versions.
